# Confirm multiply data before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import

In my app I sometimes need to import some CSV data and I wanna get a view that is shown before save imported data to provide user possibility to check that data is correct. How to achieve it in Rails?

Comment: I think this carrierwave example comes close: [Making uploads work across form redisplays](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first form field, have a hidden field name "confirm" with value 0.

In the rails controller, if the confirm is 0 you just populate with the csv data, show the form again with confirm = 1

if the confirm is 1, then it means the csv was seen by the user, so you can save it.

bonus points-
Instead of showing the csv, make a textfield out of each csv cell- the user will be able to update the fields, not just check *if* the data is correct.